# File not in downloaded save to folder after downloading finished

Tags: downloaders, flareget

I tried to download hortonworks using flareget. 7.5gb file downloaded. However I did not able to find the same in save to path. How can I find it?  Please help

Comment: See what is the default download path of flareget.

Comment: Right click>open directory shows only 0byte file. But in flareget download list it's 7.5gb completed ... Not able to find in default directory

Answer (score 1):

Brute force method regardless of how you downloaded it:

```
find / -iname '*some_part_of_filename*'
```

or

```
find / -size +7G
```

Comment: Tried this but no output ... in downloads in flarejet it's there . Then right click on list then open folder. Not finding any

Comment: I think your comment ended prematurely.  Are you saying that when you right-click the download and choose "open folder" it *does* open your file manager and show the directory, but the file's not there?  Or it doesn't open your file manager, or ?

Comment: It's opening the dialog but a file with 0kb is there .. please suggest some

Comment: I'm not familiar with flareget, but I'd guess one of two conditions:  Either it's using a temporary location to store the file while it's downloading and it's not finished yet, and it's just got the empty file there as a placeholder; or you finished downloading but somehow restarted the process and it got as far as wiping the file out but never actually started downloading again.    If you're not already familiar w/ flareget's operation, you might play with some smaller files to see how it behaves.